# Intro to Programming using C++ getting " undefined reference to '_Winmain@16' "

Tags: c++

Heres my code

```
//numbersandshit
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int name()
{
    int numb, sqnumb;

    for(numb=4; numb<=9; numb=numb+1)
    {   sqnumb=numb*numb;

        cout<<numb<<" "<<sqnumb<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and at the end I keep undefined reference to '_Winmain@16'

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It counts the number of sand grains that have been hit

Comment: @sehe: actually lol'd

Answer (score 0):

Your program needs to provide a `main()` function because it's called by your system to start the program. Rename `name()` to `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a main function.

```
int main()
```

Or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Since you're not using command line arguments, just rename `name` to `main`.

Comment: int main() worked thanks